# C++: Can boost::scoped_ptr be initialized inside a constructor?

Tags: c++, boost, scoped-ptr

Can a class member of type `boost::scoped_ptr` be initialized inside the class' constructor? How?
(Not in the initialization list)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes. you can use reset() member function.

```
class foo {
public:
    foo()
    {
         p.reset(new bar());
    }
private:
  boost::scoped_ptr<bar> p;
};
```

Comment: Is it possible to initialize it in the initialization list? If so, how?

Answer (score 6):

scoped_ptr has a method `scoped_ptr<T>::reset(T * p=0)` which you can call in your enclosing class's constructor.